# Return Type Deduction - decltype - return (x) retorna int&

Tags: c++

¿¿Qué pasa aquí??

```
int x = 1;
decltype(auto) f() { return x; }  // return type is int, same as decltype(x)
decltype(auto) f() { return(x); } // return type is int&, same as dcltype((x))
```

**Es un extracto de la documentación*

Me surge la duda de porque el decltype deduce que `return (x)` es de tipo int&

```
int x  = 1;
auto f(){
    return (x);    // return type is int&, same as decltype((x))
}

int main(){
    bool es_ref = std::is_reference<decltype(f())>::value;
    std::cout << es_ref;
}
```

Hice las pruebas y sí, pero mi duda  es si ¿se trata de una referencia anónima o qué?
En que son diferentes `return x` de `return (x)`, si `()` actua como algun operador o que tema de c++ es.

Agradezco si me encaminan a la luz.

[Function Declaration - Ir a la seccion de Return Type Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Return%20type%20deduction)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La deducción de tipos de `auto` es la misma que se usa en plantillas, eso significa que no puedes deducir los *cualificadores de segundo nivel* de los tipos.

¿Qué significa esto?, veamos algunos ejemplos. Supongamos que tenemos una función plantilla que recibe un tipo arbitrario (`T`):

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }
```

¿[Qué deduce en los siguientes casos](https://tio.run/##LchBC4IwGIDhs9@v@KCDeghCPDnzIgZeLGIdgmDInDHQOfQzCum3W6NOL@8jrd3epVzXjTaymxuFqR4mGlXdZwCketvV9EV6WWXqXiHP4DHoBtuAh7jgRE2SyGEmTFMU4nQuOL@Kw6XKeXmshHDs34zP8A2gDWFfaxOEsIAnBzORetoRnecF7jGOGHjuyv@A1wZ5ETLX8pc4Cp2PiubR4I7Be10/)?:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int CE = 42;
    int I = 42;

    f(CE);
    f(I);
    f(42);

    return 0;
}
```

Llamamos la función plantilla con un entero constante (`constexpr int`), con un entero sin cualificadores (`int`) y con un literal entero, la salida es:

> ```
> void f(T) [with T = int]
> void f(T) [with T = int]
> void f(T) [with T = int]
> ```

En ningún caso ha deducido entero constante (`const int`) cuando debería haberlo deducido por lo menos para el primer caso. Para permitir deducir incluso los cualificadores de segundo nivel, se añadió en C++14 la deducción `decltype(auto)` (tipo declarado `decltype` de la deducción `auto`).

Podemos ver la diferencia entre deducir el tipo de retorno (`auto`) y deducir el tipo declarado de la deducción (`decltype(auto)`):

```
template <typename T>
void f(T) { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

auto a()            { const std::string s; return s; }
decltype(auto) da() { const std::string s; return s; }

int main()
{
    f(a);
    f(da);

    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior produce la siguiente salida:

> ```
> void f(T) [with T = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)()]
> void f(T) [with T = const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> (*)()]
> ```

En el primer caso deduce sin los cualificadores de segundo nivel, el retorno es `std::string`, en el segundo caso incluye dichos cualificadores, el retorno es `const std::string`.

Las referencias también son cualificadores de segundo nivel, así que volviendo al ejemplo que muestras en tu código:

```
int x = 1;
decltype(auto) f() { return x; }
```

Deduce `int` porque `x` es un entero.

```
decltype(auto) f() { return(x); }
```

Deduce `int&` porque `(x)` es una expresión que resulta en un valor de lado izquierdo, es decir: una referencia a `int`.